# How can I collect performance data similar as pidstat using lttng?

Tags: lttng

By the performance data I mean like cpu, memory and disk usages for each process. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, ans I installed the PPA version, but follow the instruction about how to use lttngTop I couldn't get it run: it always return error like "can't open trace file". Is there any other way to collect these data or could anyone tell me where I got wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Which commands did you use to setup your LTTng session? Did you enable the required event contexts? It's not immediately obvious, but lttngtop needs some event contexts that are not enabled by default. From the man page:

> LTTngTop requires that the pid, procname, tid and ppid context
>   information are enabled during tracing.

This means you should issue a command like this before `lttng start`:

```
lttng add-context -k -t pid -t procname -t tid -t ppid
```